# AngularJS: Push of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, push

In my small application, I am reading a json file, display it and give the user a chance to add records to it. In the particular case, `condition` is a array in `patient` and I would like to add one item to the array (depending on the user input). No data needs to be stored or send back via POST.

**I am confused whether I need to get the information from the object `Patient` or from $scope. Nothing gets submitted.**

Is the `function addCondition` correct?

```
/* Data */
angular.module('prototypeApp')
 .factory('MedicalRecords', function($http) {
   return $http.get('scripts/data/patient_record.json');
});

/* Add more Information to Patients Conditions */
angular.module('prototypeApp')
 .controller('PatientExtConditionCtrl', function ($scope, MedicalRecords) {
        MedicalRecords.success(function(data) {
        $scope.patient = data;
          });
 });

/* Confirm Patients Conditions */
angular.module('prototypeApp')
 .controller('PatientConditionCtrl', function ($scope, MedicalRecords) {
        MedicalRecords.success(function(data) {
        $scope.patient = data;
          });
 });

/* FormController */
angular.module('prototypeApp')
 .controller('AddConditionCtrl', function () {
   this.condition = {};

   this.addCondition = function(patient){
     patient.patientCondition.push(this.condition);
   };
 });


/* in my template */

<form name="AddConditionForm" ng-controller="AddConditionCtrl" ng-submit="AddConditionCtrl.addCondition(patient)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="AddConditionCtrl.condition.hcc">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_description" ng-model="AddConditionCtrl.condition.description">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="AddConditionCtrl.condition.last_report">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
        <th>Last Reported</th>
        <th>Check</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="condition in patient.patientCondition">
        <td>{{ condition.hcc }} </td>
        <td>{{ condition.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ condition.last_report | date }}</td>
        <td> Check </td>
        </tr>       
</table>
<form action="/#/patient/conditions/ext">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Depends on what the view is doing. Please provide the code from the view (the HTML).

Comment: @HugoWood I have updated the template code. Please scroll down in the source code box. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there.

Your `addCondition` is fine. The problem seem to be that you are confusing the classic Angular controller syntax and the newer 'controller as' syntax.

**Classic syntax**

- the controller function gets the `$scope` as a parameter and adds members to it
- the controller is attached to the view with `ng-controller="controllerName"`
- members of `$scope` are accessible to the view transparently (no prefix)

  ```
  .controller('controllerName', function ($scope) {
      $scope.thing = 1
  })

  <div ng-controller="controllerName">{{thing}}</div>
  ```

**'Controller As' Syntax**

- the controller function does not need the `$scope`, instead it assigns members to `this`
- the controller is attached to the view with `ng-controller="controllerName as somePrefix"`
- members of the controller's `this` are accessible to the view through `somePrefix.fieldName`

  ```
  .controller('controllerName', function () {
      this.thing = 1
  })

  <div ng-controller="controllerName as ctrl">{{ctrl.thing}}</div>
  ```

You use the classic syntax in your first two controllers but then switch to the 'controller as' syntax, which is OK but you forgot to specify the `as prefix` part in  `ng-controller="AddConditionCtrl"`. Don't forget to update your binding to match the prefix you choose. For example, `ng-controller="AddConditionCtrl as addCondition"` means you need  `ng-model="addCondition.condition.hcc"`.

The Angular team recommends using the 'controller as' syntax because it makes the bindings more explicit since you can immediately see which field comes from which controller.

EDIT: I assume that your `form` element is a descendant of an element that has either `ng-controller="PatientExtConditionCtrl"` or `ng-controller="PatientConditionCtrl"`, so that the `patient` variable is available when the `ng-submit` executes `addCondition(patient)`.

EDIT: the details about both syntaxes can be found in [the official documentation for the ngController directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

Comment: Thank you for your extended answer. You were absolutely right. I wasn't aware of the change in the controller calling. Your answer and help is much appreciated.